Google GCE Container OS docker.io URL format
I am trying to create a GCE instance using Container OS. It fails every time with two errors:
Aug 28 16:41:35 instance-20240828-163551 systemctl[995]: Failed to start docker-events-collector.service: Unit docker-events-collector.service not found.
...
Aug 28 16:41:35 instance-20240828-163551 konlet-startup[1005]: 2024/08/28 16:41:35 Launching user container 'docker.io/XXXXX/my-image:latest'
Aug 28 16:41:35 instance-20240828-163551 konlet-startup[1005]: 2024/08/28 16:41:35 Configured container 'instance-20240828-163551' will be started with name>
Aug 28 16:41:35 instance-20240828-163551 konlet-startup[1005]: 2024/08/28 16:41:35 Pulling image: 'docker.io/XXXXX/my-image:latest'
Aug 28 16:41:35 instance-20240828-163551 konlet-startup[1005]: 2024/08/28 16:41:35 Error: Failed to start container: invalid reference format
That's not the actual docker repo name above. That was an experiment to confirm that the Docker Hub URL format is the issue.
I am using the format docker.io//: which is the only thing I've found online. Why doesn't this work? What is the correct format?
Note, the image is public. That's not the issue.
Secondly, is that first error (Failed to start docker-events-collector.service: Unit docker-events-collector.service not found) innocuous?

Instead of using the format docker.io//:, try  Uploading your Docker image to Artifact Registry,
Check if the image is present  by using this command gcloud compute images list
Then using this command to deploy:
gcloud compute instances create-with-container vm_name \
    --container-image docker_image

The second error is for logs and events, once the instance is created we can debug further on this, let me know if you can deploy an instance first.
As you have mentioned you are using format docker.io//: but official doc mentions docker.io/<full Docker image name\>
For more information follow this official document.

I know using the GCP registry is an alternate approach but loading from Docker Hub is supposed to work too.
I'm almost positive that this format used to work.

I accepted this as a solution as it works, but Google should remove the Docker Hub references from its docs.
